# CSS make right border diagonal

Tags: html, css

How can I create a vertically tilted line using css, like seen below?

[image]

Comment: _what have you **tried**_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try playing with `border`

```css
.progressbar{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 10px;
  background: #eee;
}
.progressbar > i{
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  border-top:  10px solid #0bf;          /* same as parent height */
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;   /* diagonality :) */
}
```

```html
<div class="progressbar"><i></i></div>
```